# change option menu title color

Tags: android, android-layout

That's my current output

[image]

now

How can we  change option menu title color?

Comment: May this helps you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Actionview for menu options and you can change its background

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //You can add menuitems programmatically or by inflating menu
            //Here I added programatically
            //Create your own menu item layout and add it to menu
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "");
    menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item1_layout);
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

            //We can get the menu item layout by below line of code
            View v = menu.getItem(0).getActionView();

            //You set your own color or drawable by below line of code
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_own_drawable);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```